# How to create a new project in Visual Studio Code in 2020?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, vscode-tasks

I wanted to create an ASP.NET Web API project using VS Code, but in my editor I am not getting new project option:

[image: Screenshot of VS Code welcome page on my laptop]

As you can see I have only new file option.

Please can anyone help me with this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Create a .NET Core WebApi project named "HelloWorldApi".

1. Start Visual Studio Code.
2. Select File > Open Folder (File > Open... on macOS) from the main menu.
3. In the Open Folder dialog, create a HelloWorldApi folder and click Select Folder (Open on macOS). The folder name becomes the project name and the namespace name by default.
4. Open the Terminal in Visual Studio Code by selecting View > Terminal from the main menu.
5. The Terminal opens with the command prompt in the HelloWorldApi folder.
6. In the Terminal, enter the following command: `dotnet new webapi`

```
C:\HelloWorldApi> dotnet new webapi
The template "ASP.NET Core Web API" was created successfully.

Processing post-creation actions...
Running 'dotnet restore' on C:\HelloWorldApi.csproj...
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored C:\HelloWorldApi.csproj (in 191 ms).

Restore succeeded.
```

The template creates a simple base WebApi project.

To run the API, in the console, type: `dotnet run`

```
C:\HelloWorldApi> dotnet run
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\HelloWorldApi
```

Answer (score 1):

Luis gave correct answer. I would add more on that.

1. Go to the folder which will contain whole repository.
2. Run below command:

`dotnet new webapi --framework "net6.0" --language "C#" -o MyPersonal.Hello.World.Api/src`

Above command will create new folder with name of `MyPersonal.Hello.World.Api` and a sub directory as `src`. The web api project will be created inside `src` with C# language. You can see files and folders created with boiler plate code for Web Api.

Now if you want to add a Unit Test project in the `test` sub directory then run below command:

`dotnet new mstest --framework "net6.0" --language "C#" -o MyPersonal.Hello.World.Api/test/Hello.World.Unit.Tests`

Your project folder structure will look like this:
[image]

For more information please go through Microsoft's [dotnet new TEMPLATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new) page.